# third-order nonlinear differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the following differential question:

$$\frac{-1}{2}\frac{1}{(f'(x))^{2}} S(f)(x)=K,$$
where

$$ S(f)(x) = \frac{f'''}{f'} - \frac{3}{2}(\frac{f''}{f'})^{2}$$
is Schwartzian derivative of real valued function of one real variable $f=f(x)$ and $K\in \mathbb{R}$.

Thanks.

Comment: First of all you can convert your equation to a 2nd order equation since there is no term with unknown function $f(x)$ in equation.

Comment: You sure its not $$S(f)(x) = \frac{f'''}{f'} -3\left(\frac{f''}{f'}\right)^2$$? because this has a straightforward solution. As the other solution of mine involves Hyper-geometric functions with another integration left..so please check before I put myself through that pain.

Comment: @Chinny84 Be sure it's not, because OP mentions Schwartzian derivative and it has coefficient $\frac{3}{2}$

Comment: @Evgeny Ah..I just noticed that in the question (not that I have heard of that before ;) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, as @Evgeny suggests, let $g(x)=f'(x)$. Then the differential equation becomes
$$
\frac{1}{g}\Bigl(\frac{g''}{g}-\frac{3}{2}\Bigl(\frac{g'}{g}\Bigr)^2\Bigr)=-2K.
$$
Next, the differential equation becomes a simpler if you let $h(x)=1/g(x)$. Note that then $g(x)=1/h(x)$, so (using the product rule and chain rule),
$$
g'=-\frac{1}{h^2}h'\quad \text{and}\quad g''=2\frac{(h')^2}{h^3}-\frac{h''}{h^2}.
$$
Inserting all this in the differential equation for $h$, we find that
$$
h^2\Bigl(2\frac{(h')^2}{h^2}-\frac{h''}{h}-\frac{3}{2}\Bigl(\frac{h'}{h}\Bigr)^2\Bigr)=-2K,
$$
or, simplified,
$$
\frac{1}{2}(h')^2-hh''=-2K.
$$
As mentioned in the comments, differentiating this leads to
$$
hh'''=0
$$
*If* we assume that $h\neq 0$, we find that $h'''=0$, and so $h=Ax^2+Bx+C$. If you insert this into the equation for $h$, you might determine some constant in term of $K$.

I leave it to you go to back to $f$ (via $g$, maybe).

Comment: It's still curious how to proceed further, because l.h.s. isn't a derivative of any $C \cdot h^{\alpha} \cdot (h^\prime)^{\beta}$ and I can't imagine function more complex that these right now :)

Comment: @Evgeny The solution to the equation in $h$ is a second degree polynomial.

Comment: @Evgeny If the equation for $h$ is differentiated once, you will find that $h(x)h'''(x)=0$.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the idea!

Comment: @mickep If $h(x)=\frac{1}{f'(x)}$, then we have:$\frac{-h^{2}}{2}(\frac{h''}{h'}-\frac{2h'}{h}-\frac{3}{2}(\frac{h'}{h})^{2})=K$. How do you obtain $\frac{1}{2}(h'(x))^{2}-h(x)h''(x) = -2K$?

Comment: From [this geometry article][http://arxiv.org/pdf/0802.2166.pdf]                             $$f(x)=K^{\frac{-1}{2}}\arctan(K^{\frac{1}{2}}(ax+b)/(cx+d))$$
where$a, b, c, d\in \mathbb{R}$ with $ad − bc=\pm 1$.(4th page, 9th line)

Comment: @user I have now updated the answer, with the details.

Comment: @user, it is true that the function you write above solves the differential equation. One can also write a solution as $f(x)=1/\sqrt{K}\arctan(ax+b)+c$, where $a$, $b$ and $c$ are arbitrary constants.

Comment: @mickep, OK. very thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Let $p = f'$ we obtain
$$
-\frac{1}{2}\frac{p''}{p^3} +\frac{3}{4}\left(\frac{p'}{p}\right)^2\frac{1}{p^2} = K
$$
we can rwerite as
$$
\frac{p''}{p^3}-\frac{3}{2}\left(\frac{p'}{p^2}\right)^2 = \\
\frac{p'}{p^3}\dfrac{d}{dp}p' -\frac{3}{2}\left(\frac{p'}{p^2}\right)^2 = 0
$$
now trying solutions of the form:
$$
p' = p^{\alpha}\phi(p) 
$$
we obtain
$$
\alpha p^{2(\alpha-2)}\phi^2 + p^{2\alpha-3}\phi\phi' -\frac{3}{2}p^{2(\alpha-2)}\phi^2 = -2K
$$
choosing $\alpha = 2$
$$
2\phi^2  + p\phi\phi' - \frac{3}{2}\phi^2 = p\phi\phi' + \frac{1}{2}\phi^2 = -2K 
$$
or 
$$
p\dfrac{d}{dp}\phi^2 = -4k - \phi^2
$$
separable or if we set $\phi = 2\sqrt{K}\sqrt{v}$
$$
4K p \frac{dv}{dp} = -4K(1+v)
$$
or
$$
\int \frac{1}{1+v}dv = -\int \frac{1}{p}dp
$$
$$
\ln(1+v) = -\ln p + C \implies 1+ v = \frac{A}{p}
$$
or
$$
\phi = \sqrt{4K} \sqrt{\frac{A}{p}-1}
$$
and finally
$$
p' = p^2\sqrt{4K} \sqrt{\frac{A}{p}-1} = \sqrt{4K}p^{3/2}\sqrt{A-p}
$$
now integrate that..as 
$$
\int p^{-3/2}(A-p)^{1/2} = \sqrt{4K}x + C
$$
where using the final sub of $p = Au$
we obtain
$$
\frac{1}{A}\int u^{-3/2}(1-u)^{-1/2} du = \frac{1}{A}\int \frac{2}{v^2\sqrt{1-v^2}}dv
$$