# What are methods available for solving 3rd ODE directly without reducing to a 1st order system of IVP?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request, numerical-methods, symbolic-computation

I have came across the questions: [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/109554/third-order-cauchy-euler-differential-equation?rq=1), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1772908/third-order-differential-equations?rq=1), [3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1097742/third-order-nonlinear-differential-equation?rq=1).

In these questions you can see different third order ordinary differential equations (ODEs):

$$y'''=f( x, y, y', y''), y(a)=y_0, y'(a)=y_1, y''(a)=y_2.\text{ }(1)$$ 
As I know a third order equation is rare situation on practice.

I know the [Abraham–Lorentz–Dirac–Langevin equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abraham%E2%80%93Lorentz_force) only.

**Edit.**
@Matt gives the link on the [KdV equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korteweg%E2%80%93de_Vries_equation).

I have found the 3rd ODE which arises in [modeling draining or coating fluid flow problems](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/pdf/10.1137/0524010).

**Question**

What are **symbolic** and **numerical** methods available for solving 3rd ODE directly? i.e. without reducing to a 1st order system of inital value problem (IVP)?

Currently, I have found the [linearizing tangent transformation](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0747717116000079) which leads the equation (1) into the linear second-order ODE.

Comment: There are lots of different numerical methods for solving any order ODE. Two that spring to mind are the finite difference approach and spectral methods.

Comment: You have changed the question so that Matt's response is no longer a  valid answer to the changed question. Please do not do this.

Answer (score 2):

A very famous 3rd order equation is the [KdV equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korteweg%E2%80%93de_Vries_equation).

This equation describes shallow water waves.  If you look for traveling wave solutions (keeping the same shape and fixed velocity), then the PDE transforms to a 3rd order ODE.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I have updated the question.